# Adding new entries over entity navigation property collection

Tags: entity-framework-6

I need to create a generic way to add missing languages entries to all entities in which implements an specific interface. I found out how to get my collection property, but I still don't know **how to add new values on it before** proceed to save.

Following a piece of my `public override int SaveChanges()` handling.

```
foreach (var translationEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries(<ITranslation>))
{
    if (translationEntity.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        var translationEntries = translationEntity.Entity.GetType()
                                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                .Where(x => x.CanWrite &&
                                x.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual &&
                                x.PropertyType.IsGenericType == true &&
                                typeof(IEnumerable<ILanguage>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType) == true);

        foreach (var translationEntry in translationEntries)
        {
            //Add missing items.
        }
    }
}
```

Classes code samples

```
public partial class FileType : ITranslation
{
    public long FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AcceptType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileTypeTranslation> FileTypeTranslations { get; set; }

    public FileType()
    {
        this.FileTypeTranslations = new HashSet<FileTypeTranslation>();
    }
}

public class FileTypeTranslation : EntityTranslation<long, FileType>, ILanguage
{
    [Required]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}


public partial class ElementType : ITranslation
{
    public long ElementTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ElementTypeTranslation> ElementTypeTranslations { get; set; }

    public ElementType()
    {
        this.ElementTypeTranslations = new HashSet<FileTypeTranslation>();
    }
}

public class ElementTypeTranslation : EntityTranslation<long, ElementType>, ILanguage
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell more? What is not working? how does the code adding new translation entites look like?

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek just imagine you have a Model with some collection property and that you want to Modify this collection from your ChangeTracker. Please, also consider this collection has a known structure.

Comment: OK, but what is not working in the code above? I understant that you call base.SaveCahnges as the last thing in your override method, so it should do what you want. Is this collection part of ITranslation interface? Or is this collection of ITranslation objects?

Comment: The code above is just returning collection property but **I can't modify it by adding or removing anything - I have no these methods**. I also tried to use `translationEntity.Collection("MyCollectionName");` but I also don't have add or remove methods. No, the collection is not part of ITranslation.

Comment: then you have to get all entries that have propety Translations and modify their collections. The method in your code just gets all added translations. You have to find all parents

Comment: So... and do you know how do I do this from DbContext ChangeTracker?

Comment: You have use above method to find all modified enitites of all classes that have Translations property. The easiest way is through interface like ITranslationsContainer that has one public property ICollection<ITranslation> Translations. What is your logic for that adding? All thing with Translations should always have all of them?

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek please, have a look my updated post. Notice ElementType and FileType classes has ICollection properties with different names. ICollection not implements any interface. I just need to find them from ChangeTracker during the adding process and add extra translations that by chance were missing. The `translationEntries` brings me the Collection, but I don't know how to get the object dynamically and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Entries from ChangeTracker have property called Entity which holds original entity

```
foreach (var fileType in ChangeTracker.Entries(<FileType>))
{
  fileType.Entity.FileTypeTranslations.Add();
}
```

and for ElementType:

```
foreach (var elementType in ChangeTracker.Entries(<ElementType>))
{
   elementType.Entity.ElementTypeTranslations.Add();
}
```

I didn't test, but it was too long to paste in comment.

Comment: That's the point, but I didn't want to handle one by one of entities that could have a Collection. That's why I was getting them by the Interface and then trying to get the collection that certainly will exist. I'm using reflection to reach this but I don't know how to transform the found collection property on this object in yout strong typed example.

Comment: I am afraid that that's impossible. You would have to run pretty complex refrection search to find all types with property with type of ICollection<ITranslation>. I suggest you go with shorter way and define ITranslationContainer or ITranslatable as I stated in my comment and make FileType and ElementType implement it. Then just go through all ChangeTracker.Entries<ITranslatable>