# Cast PropertyInfo to Collection

Tags: c#, casting

How do I cast a collection property in order to manage it? Please, take a look the attached image. I need to get the collection by it's name, and then work with this collection to add, remove, etc.

[image]

Comment: Post your code, not an image of your code (especially an image of your code that features an error message in another language...)

Comment: @maccettura I usually post the code. Exceptionally in this question I posted an image in order to better demonstrate the question. My apologies about the language and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `PropertyInfo` (which is just metadata information about the property) to its value type; you have to go through the `GetValue` method.

That method will take an instance to retrieve from or null if it's static. The result is an `object` that you then cast:

```
ICollection collection = (ICollection)myCollectionProperty.GetValue(myEntity);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. My property is a type of `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`. Would you please have a better approach to reach I'm trying to?

Comment: @RubensMussiCury You'll need to be a lot more specific about what you are trying to accomplish; if you need to get the field via reflection (seems unlikely since you know the name...) this is the way.

Comment: please have a look this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567964/adding-new-entries-over-entity-navigation-property-collection). I have "n" classes that contains a virtual collection of some translated properties. I'm just trying to find a way to handle the adding process through ChangeTracker in order to check which languages are missing and add them over my entity Translation collection before to save. I can take in a strong-typed way `MyEntity.MyEntityTranslations` and manage as desired, but I would like to make it for all entities that has this collection.