# Why to Load() entity collection before remove it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I've noticed that all the times I removed an entity, it's relationships were not removing from Db as expected. I solved this behavior by loading the collections before to remove them, like this

`context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();`

My question is: Based on [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx), considering Lazy Loading is correctly enabled, **why should I Load() my entity relationships to guarantee they will be also removed?** Or... may I'm doing something wrong?!

**Classes**

```
public partial class Profile
{
    public long ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    public Profile()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        this.Profiles = new HashSet<Profile>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

**Relation Config**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
            .HasMany<Role>(r => r.Roles)
            .WithMany(p => p.Profiles)
            .Map(pr =>
            {
                pr.MapLeftKey("ProfileId");
                pr.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                pr.ToTable("ProfileRole");
            });
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Profile_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Profile profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentProfile = db.Profile.Find(profile.ProfileId);
        //Removing this line, Roles are NOT removed from deleted Profile.
        db.Entry(currentProfile).Collection(cp => cp.Roles).Load();

        db.Profile.Attach(currentProfile);
        db.Profile.Remove(currentProfile);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't be needed (with or w/o lazy loading) if the cascade delete is on, is it?

Comment: That's what I exactly thought. Yes cascade deletes are on by default. An important thing I might had to tell is that I'm using MySQL Connector.

Comment: @ivan-stoev I updated the post with some code samples.

Comment: I've tried your sample (EF v6.1.3, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 v4.0.30319) and it works - EF issues single `DELETE` command and cascade delete does the rest. Assuming the passed `Profile profile` object is not from the same context, i.e. `currentProfile != profile`.

Comment: @IvanStoev you got it! I was working with 2 different context, that's why sometimes cascade deletion was working during debug process, I guess probably because of any kind contexts sync. **If you would like to answer this question to get an answer mark pointing that context mistake, I'll do it!**, plus if by chance you have a good EF Reflection background and could help me here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595181/add-items-to-an-entity-collection-via-changetracker), I would be so thankful. Thanks a lot!